# MSMQ Server error

Tags: msmq

I am configuring, turning windows features, on Windows 7 for MSMQ, but after I checked all the child nodes under the MSMQ, I am having an error, all features are not installed successfully.
I tried installing Microsoft Fix, for updates, but that did not fix it.
How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Hmm...There is an error. You did not say what it is. You installed a fix and did not say what it is. So basically you just want a sounding board.

Comment: The error was not clearly stated, it just says all components are not installed successfully. The component I installed is a Microsoft update fix.

Comment: I turned on the features one by one MSMQ ;- Active Directory Domain Services Integration, Triggers, and Multicasting Support and they went well. but, Http support is still throwing an error.

Comment: Add the error you are getting. The details of the fix that you applied.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing
I have already stated the error and the detail of the fix.

Comment: Anything in event logs?

Comment: @John  where do I get the log ?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722404.aspx